# Marking CC in the mails sent through MailLoggers of nant

Tags: nant

We can send mails through mailLoggers using the properties MailLogger.success.to or MailLogger.failure.to. Can we make carbon copies in the mails that are sent through MailLogger

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the core `MailLogger` to send cc messages.   NAnt uses `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` but [does not set the cc value](http://nant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nant/nant/src/NAnt.Core/Log.cs?revision=1.49&view=markup#l_897).  It would not be difficult to extend the functionality of `MailLogger` to have cc if you needed it.